# I'm trying to make a Login alert in Swift but the code doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

     PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: self.txtEmailSignin.text!, password: self.txtPasswordSignin.text!) {

        (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Login Successfully", message: "")
        } else {
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define doesn't work. Is `displayAlert(withTitle:message:)` called? What's the code of that method?

Comment: Please include the code for displayAlert() and indicate where you have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you want to update any UI element in iOS app, the UI should be always updated in the main queue.

Note: Here in your sample code you are performing login request in the background thread it seems. So you are required to update the alert UI in the main thread.

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: self.txtEmailSignin.text!, password: self.txtPasswordSignin.text!) {
    (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    if user != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Login Successfully", message:"")
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}}
```

**Edit:** And your alert display helper function will look like this, and which should be added in the same `ViewController`

```
func displayAlert(withTitle: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: withTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: the error said <Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'displayAlert'>

Comment: Do you have a function `displayAlert ` declared in your ViewController?

Comment: No, how can I declare it?